# Using UIRefreshControl with UISearchBar search results

Tags: tableview, uisearchbar, uisearchdisplaycontroller, uirefreshcontrol, tableheader

I'm trying to get a behavior like the Mail app where there is a `UISearchBar` and you can pull to refresh the search results. Currently, I have the Search Display Controller with the `UISearchBar` connected in IB and everything works fine (I can refresh when in the main `tableview` and I can search).

But when I search and try to pull to refresh the search results (like the mail app), there is no `UIRefreshControl`. Check the video below:

[Screen Recording](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Gpq8GMTL3wQ&feature=youtube_gdata_player)

I guess I have to make the `UISearchBar` the `headerView` of the `tableView` but I can't reference the `UISearchBar` since it's an outlet of the Search Display Controller in IB. Here is my code for the `UIRefreshControl` :

```
    //Pull to Refresh
    refreshControl = [[UIRefreshControl alloc] init];
    [refreshControl addTarget:self action:@selector(pullToRefresh)      
    forControlEvents:UIControlEventValueChanged];


    [self.carTableView addSubview:refreshControl];
```

I'm using the above code in the `-viewDidLoad` method of the `UIViewController` that contains the `tableView`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the problem by creating another `UIRefreshControl` and adding it to the `UISearchDispayController` every time the user type a search text in the search bar which I can detect in `- (void)searchDisplayController:(UISearchDisplayController *)controller didLoadSearchResultsTableView:(UITableView *)tableView` . Here is the code:

```
//in viewDidLoad
//Pull to refresh in the search
    searchRefreshControl = [[UIRefreshControl alloc] init];
    [searchRefreshControl addTarget:self action:@selector(pullToRefresh) forControlEvents:UIControlEventValueChanged];
```

Then:

```
//in - (void)searchDisplayController:(UISearchDisplayController *)controller didLoadSearchResultsTableView:(UITableView *)tableView

//add the refresh control to the search display controller tableview
    [self.searchDisplayController.searchResultsTableView addSubview:searchRefreshControl];
```